# Airflow-2 custom api auth_backend

Tags: google-cloud-platform, airflow, google-iap

As we need to use stable REST API from Airflow-2.X onwards, does anyone has any success / idea / example on how to create custom api auth_backend as suggested on this page [airflow-api](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/2.1.4/security/api.html#roll-your-own-api-authentication) to override authentication (allowing all request) ?

We would like to implement the similar flow/function as Airflow-1 where REST API / Experimental where default config able to accept everything/unauthenticated - yes it is a security risk but we do have IAP layer to secure the traffic. I also noticed that Google Cloud Composer has its own API backend for Airflow-2 called airflow.composer.api.backend.composer_auth

TIA

Comment: I too am looking for a solution or an example to implement the custom authentication as given in the reference page you shared.

Comment: Would also love to know. Have a similar setup of IAP-protected airflow.